# Using whereIn with different column names (Eloquent)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, where-in

I have an array `$toolIds` containing only `tool_id` I want to use for selection from the `tools` table but the column names do not match and therefore it fails. I read in another thread that it would work if the array for matching (`toolsIds`) would only contain one column but this is not the case. My (not working) code:

```
$tools = DB::table('tools')->select('id','title')
  ->whereIn('tool_id',$toolIds)
  ->get();
```

The JSON output for the two arrays is:

```
toolid: [{"tool_id":"1155"},{"tool_id":"1136"}]

tools: [{"id":"1155","title":"Shemar Zieme"},{"id":"1136","title":"Mr. Johnny Hagenes DDS"}]
```

Comment: Is `$toolIds` array only contains id like  [1,2,3,4,5] ? and does `tools` table have `tool_id` column?

Comment: No, it's the other way. I added the Json output to my question to show the array contents.

Comment: Is the name of your column `tool_id` ?

Comment: You see the column names in the Jason output: `toolIds` has only the column `tool_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel `whereIn` accepts only flat array without keys. See [where clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses).

You must **pluck** ids in $toolIds array as below: (with [array_pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#arrays))

```
$toolIds = [
    ["tool_id"=>"1155"],
    ["tool_id"=>"1136"]
];

$plucked_ids = array_pluck($toolIds, 'tool_id'); // $plucked_ids = ["1155", "1136"];

$tools = DB::table('tools')->select('id','title')
  ->whereIn('id', $plucked_ids) // and we check tools.id column not tool_id.
  ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks! By the way: For Laravel 7 it's `Arr::pluck($toolIds, 'tool_id');`

Answer (score 0):

You could use whereJsonContains to query JSON arrays

Follow laravel [documentation:](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#json-where-clauses), hope this would be helpful

Comment: Thanks but I don't see how this can help, because with `->whereJsonContains('id',$toolIds)` it seems to be the same problem. Stil, `toolIds` does not contain a column `id` and therefore the ids can't be found in `toolIds`. Or did I get the syntax wrong?